# Is the time X:30 said as "half past X" or "half to X"?

Tags: time

Is the time **X:30** should be said only as "half **past** X" or it is possible also to say "half **to** X"?

For example:
`It is 4:30 AM.`

It is "half **past** four" or also "half **to** five"?

Comment: Either the "0" in "04" or the "AM" is redundant.  If "04:30" is pronounced as "oh-four-thirty", that implies military time.  Military time uses a 24-hour clock, so 04:30 is 4:30 AM, and 16:30 ("sixteen thirty") is 4:30 PM.

Comment: In British colloquial usage (but not American, I believe) this is also said as "half four".

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87704/why-half-past-and-not-half-to

Answer (score 3):

I would say "half past 0X".  I don't know if anyone regulates this, but I do not recall ever hearing "half to 0X".

Comment: I have never heard "half to", and if I did hear it I would be dubious what the speaker meant.

Answer (score 2):

In the analog clock days it was usual to say "a quarter past five" and "a quarter to six". Similarly "ten minutes" etc. instead of quarter. As far as i recall, "Half past" was the way the half-hour was called - "half to" could be understood, but it would sound odd.

Nowadays, it is more common to call the time as it appears on a digital clock, so "ten fifteen", "five thirty", "eleven forty-five". The quarters and halves are not incorrect but young people may have a hard time with them....

This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=half+past+six%2C+half+to+seven%2C+six+thirty&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalf%20past%20six%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chalf%20to%20seven%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csix%20thirty%3B%2Cc0) is one example of a comparison.